# Install official NVIDIA drivers 32 bit version

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 64-bit, steam

I use Ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on a PC with a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 graphics cards.

I have installed the official 64 bits NVIDIA Drivers downloaded from [here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).

[image]

Now, when I try to run Steam I get the error:

> glxChooseVisual failed

It seems that error comes because steam cannot find the 32 bits drivers of my graphics card.

How can I install the 32 bits drivers version?

I've found this package for Linux 32 bits, NVIDIA-Linux-x86-390.87.run, but when I try to run it I get:

> ERROR: this .run file is intended for the Linux-x86 platform, but you
>   appear to be running on Linux-x86_64.  Aborting installation.

I'm not sure if it is safe to install the 32 bits from another source or if I can install both versions of the drivers. Or maybe there is another solution to fix this problem.

Comment: I would completely remove the driver installed via the .run & undo anything else you did concerning that install, if anything. Then install the packaged version of nvidia drivers, either from default Ubuntu repo or the drivers ppa, https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa  Then when installing you'll get both amd64 & i386 installed automatically.